# how to pass button id from table to modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup

i have this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<input type="button" name="EditBtn1" onclick="showPopup('<?php echo $rs['appointment_id']; ?>')" class="" value="<?php echo $rs['appointment_id']; ?>" style="">


<script>
                                                function showPopup(id) {
  document.getElementById('id01').style.display = 'block';
  updateURL(id);
}

function updateURL(id) {
  // Get the current URL
  var currentURL = window.location.href;
  
  // Check if the URL already contains the 'id' parameter
  if (currentURL.includes('?id=')) {
    // Update the 'id' parameter value
    var updatedURL = currentURL.replace(/(\?id=)[^\&]+/, '$1' + id);
    history.replaceState(null, '', updatedURL);
  } else {
    // Append the 'id' parameter to the URL
    var updatedURL = currentURL + '?id=' + id;
    history.replaceState(null, '', updatedURL);
  }
}

</script> this code is working well but the sql fetch id first before id updated in url   $id = $_GET['id'];

  // Prepare the SQL statement

    // Prepare the SQL statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `appointments` WHERE appointment_id='$id'";
```

when i click button the id of button passing to URL AND the data in popup thats fetched from database  depend of URL
problem if i click button id 6 and then click button id 4 is showing me data of id 6 and then if i click button id 10 is showing me data of id 4 and if i click buton id 7 is showing me data of id 10 etc help

here is model

```
<div class="w3-container">
    <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
        <div class="w3-modal-content">
            <div class="w3-container">
     

            <br>
            <form id="editForm" method="POST" action="">
           
    <?php
  



  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    // Prepare the SQL statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `appointments` WHERE appointment_id='$id'";


    // Execute the query
    $getOfferType = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        if (mysqli_num_rows($getOfferType) >= 1) {
            $sn = 1;
            while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($getOfferType)) {

                ?>
                            <tr>
                                <input type="hidden" id="appointmentId" name="EdiBbtn" value="<?php echo $rs[0]; ?>">
                                <label for="appointmentDate">Appointment Date:</label>


                     
        
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="ExpireDate" name="appointmentDate" 
          min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>"
          
          value=
           <?php
           echo $rs[3];
           ?>
         >
          
         <br>
         <br>



                                <label for="appointmentTime">Appointment Time:</label>
<input type="time" id="appointmentTime" style="" value="<?php echo $rs[4]; ?>" name="appointmentTime" oninput="updateAppointmentTime(this.value)"><br><br>

<script>
    function updateAppointmentTime(value) {
        var timeParts = value.split(":");
        var hours = timeParts[0];
        var minutes = timeParts[1];
       
        console.log("Hours: " + hours);
        console.log("Minutes: " + minutes);
    }
</script>










                                <label for="serviceType">Service Type:</label>



                                
<select class="form-select"  name="newSkill" id="newSkill" 
 onchange="getValue1(this)" required>

          <option selected disabled > <?php echo $rs[5]; ?></option>
          <option value="1">procedure</option>    
    <option value="2">checkup</option>
    <option value="3">consultation</option>
    <option value="4">Dentistry</option>
    <option value="5">General Medicine</option>


    
</select>


          
<input type="hidden" id="serviceType" value="<?php echo $rs[5]; ?>" name="serviceType"><br><br>

<script>
function getValue1(obj)
{  
   // it will return the selected text
   // obj variable will contain the object of check box
   var text = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].innerHTML ; 
   
   document.getElementById('serviceType').value=text;
   

}
</script>


                                <label for="appointmentStatus">Appointment Status:</label>
<select class="form-select"  name="newSkill" id="newSkill" 
 onchange="getValue(this)" required>

          <option selected disabled > <?php echo $rs[7]; ?></option>
          <option value="1">Pending</option>    
    <option value="2">Confirmed</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="textch" value="<?php echo $rs[7];?>" name="appointmentStatus" required>
<script>
function getValue(obj)
{  
   // it will return the selected text
   // obj variable will contain the object of check box
   var text = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].innerHTML ; 
   
   document.getElementById('textch').value=text;


}
</script>












                        <br><br>
                                <label for="createdAt">Created At:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="createdAt" name="createdAt" value="<?php echo $rs[8]; ?>" name="createdAt">
                            </tr>
                    <?php
                        }}}
                      else {
                        // No appointments found
                        echo "No appointments found.";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <br>
                    <div class="modal-footer" style="">
                        <button type="submit" name="updateBtn" class="w3-button w3-green">Update</button>
                        <br><br>
                    </div>











                    
                </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```